# Cell segmentation of cell culture images: wrong classification of background pixels

Tags: matlab, background, cell, image-segmentation

I need to segment some cells of cell culture images and I have some problems with some background regions wrongly classified as foreground.

I've some good results using `imbothat` matlab function for background subtraction (there is a lot of uniform illumination) followed by `gmm` for classifying in 2 regions (background vs cells).

However, `imbothat` renders some background pixels very similar to cells regions and subsequently `gmm` (binarization threshold may vary a lot among images and I don't want to subjectively choose it) performs a bad classification.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

I've tried adding some extra data to `gmm` (apart from `Igraywobvd`), such as the `stdfilts` or `entropyfilts`, without any improvement of the results.

If I reduce `strel` to 20 (or less) these "problematic" background regions are not so highlighted, but I lose many cell regions...

This is the original image:

[image]

This is the sequence I obtain (indicating the wrong classified regions):

https://ibb.co/X8KY98V

My matlab code below:

```
for  jpg_file=1:length(jpgsinfolder)

I=original_images{jpg_file}; %figure; imshow(original)
Igray=rgb2gray(I); %figure; imshow(Igray)

%Substract background
Igraywob=imbothat(imadjust(Igray), strel('disk',50)); %figure; 
imshow(Igraywob)

%GMM 
%Convert input images to double vectors and generate the dataset
Igraywobvd=double(Igraywob(:));
%Add data to the final dataset
gmm_dataset=horzcat(Igraywobvd);
%GMM
opt = statset('MaxIter',15000,'TolFun',1e-6);
gmm =fitgmdist(gmm_dataset,2,'Options',opt,'CovType','diagonal','RegularizationValue',0.01);
 %----Probability of our pixels to belong to the fitted distributions
prob = gmm.posterior(gmm_dataset);
%------save labels of the major probability
[val, labels_gmm] = max(prob,[],2); 
%Reshape vector with the original image size
labels_gmm=reshape(labels_gmm,size(Igray,1),size(Igray,2));  %figure; 
imagesc(labels_gmm2)
%Chose the labels with highest intensity (corresponding to the cells)
med1=mean2(Igray(labels_gmm==1));
med2=mean2(Igray(labels_gmm==2));
if med1>med2
    labels_gmm(labels_gmm==1)=0;
    labels_gmm(labels_gmm==2)=1;
else
    labels_gmm(labels_gmm==1)=1;
    labels_gmm(labels_gmm==2)=0;
end
%Binarization
labels_gmm_bin=labels_gmm>0;  %figure; imshow(labels_gmm)
%Delete small objects (artifacts)
labels_gmm_op=bwareaopen(labels_gmm_bin, 500); %figure; imshow(labels_gmm_op)
%Close small holes inside the cells
cellmask=imclose(labels_gmm_op, strel('disk',1));

%Can see the final result:
cellmask_results = labeloverlay(Igray,cellmask,'Transparency',0.7); 
figure(jpg_file); imshow(cellmask_results)

end
```

Comment: You could try to apply an morphological opening (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) to filter out the small regions, but it would also remove the thin regions of the objects, I'm not sure if this is a problem.